# Could not find gem 'neo4j-enterprise (>= 0) ruby'

Tags: ruby, neo4j, rubygems, bundler

When I run

```
gem install neo4j-enterprise
```

the gem cannot be found:

ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'neo4j-enterprise' (>= 0) in any repository

All other gem install perfectly fine, this is the only one that fails. Nevertheless it should be there:
https://rubygems.org/gems/neo4j-enterprise

where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a jRuby-only gem.  Your error message includes 'neo4j-enterprise (>= 0) **ruby**' which means (I think) that you're using an MRI-ish version of Ruby

If you meant to use jRuby then obviously you can switch to that.  If you meant to use Neo4j with MRI via Neo4j's HTTP REST endpoints you can install the Neo4j server.  See the Setup guide:

http://neo4jrb.readthedocs.org/en/5.2.x/Setup.html

Comment: can I connect natively to the neo4j-database-files without jruby at all? There is another error: `create_session': Can't connect to database 'embedded_db', available server_db (Neo4j::Session::InitializationError)

Comment: Unfortunately not.  Since Neo4j is written in Java, being able to load the Neo4j libraries into your Ruby application requires jRuby.  For non-jRuby your only option is HTTP, though in Neo4j 3.0 they plan to have a new binary protocol for better network performance